# C# Adding multiple lines to pastebin breaks whitelist system

Tags: c#, key, whitelist

I am currently making a whitelist system program and whenever I add another line to the pastebin, the entire thing breaks on me leaving me to only be able to do 1 line.

```cs
string key = Console.ReadLine();
                string whitelist = new System.Net.WebClient() { Proxy = null }.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/shzKS0RB");
                string blacklist = new System.Net.WebClient() { Proxy = null }.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/gQmWxkjA");

                    if (key.Contains(whitelist))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine(" [WHITELISTED] YOUR KEY HAS BEEN WHITELISTED SUCCESSFULLY!");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto Panel;
                }
                if (key.Contains(blacklist))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.WriteLine(" [BLACKLISTED] YOUR KEY IS UNFORTUNATELY BLACKLISTED FROM OUR SYSTEM!");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    Console.WriteLine(" [INVALID KEY] THE KEY YOU HAVE INPUTTED IS INVALID!");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto key;
                }
```

But inspecting the data in a web browser shows me the items in separate lines

```
<pre>R93UBR-20QM48-QME677-P4KGM1-7L0GKY
testkey2
testkey3
testkey4</pre>
```

Comment: You should consider editing your question and adding what did the `whitelist` variable received

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @xkazi why would you expect that to different strings are `Equal` to another? (Also please don't use `goto`. It is outdated for over 30 years now.)

Comment: I just had it like that, the `(key.Contains(whitelist))` causes the exact same problem

Comment: What should I use other than `goto`? I'm new to C#

Comment: Of course that doesn't work, why would the key contain the whole whitelist? Hard to say what to use without seeing the whole code. Maybe create a question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once everything works.